# How does Google Plus check if a profile name is correct?

Tags: google, google-plus

Google used to suspend profiles for incorrect names. Though based on one's country of origin, there may be names that may not seem legitimate to english-speaking nations.

If they used to suspend on the basis of flag/report submitted by other Google Plus users, then is it possible that me or bunch of my friends report a profile name that results in a suspension of that profile?

Comment: Have you looked at the [official help page regarding Reporting Inappropriate Profiles](http://www.google.com/support/profiles/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1257354&answer=97707)?

Answer (score 4):

There is a story about [google's ID verification](http://gewalker.blogspot.com/2011/08/firsthand-examination-of-google-profile.html) I read just this morning that would be relevant to your question. It seams that if people report your name as fake or for impersonation, a simple photo ID scanned and emailed is all you need to get back on course. As it turns out in the story, even a fake photo ID will pass the test and get your account a green light.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for one there are the types of profile names that are easily identified as "false" names, e.g. historical figures who do not live anymore or entities such as MLP- or rageface-characters (I already found the "FFFUUUU"-guy and the "Y U NO"-guy).

And then theres the case of legitimate-sounding fake names which are basically undetectable (if your name is Peter you can name yourself Frank. Who's going to spot it's fake except for friends who'd need to report you?)

And then there are nicknames. And I have no idea how they want to manage that.
Besides the fact that the Google community standards don't strictly prohibit the use of pseudonyms and the whole problem is therefor a little pointless in my eyes. And frustrating.

But as far as your question about the reporting goes, I think that's the way it works.
I'm from Germany, and yes, every fascism/Nazi/denounciation joke was already posted in my G+-Stream.